# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker v4 disable dates

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am working on a datetimepicker and want to disable all the future dates except today,  here is my code:

```
$('#textFromDate').datetimepicker(function () {   
  maxDate:new Date()
  autoclose: true
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"all the future dates except today"* well today is not future date anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally I have googled the working Answer.......

```
$("#textFromDate").datetimepicker( {       
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',                   
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    maxDate: 'now'     
});
```